# python, qtreewidgetitem, numpy matrix and image widget

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I would like to create a json file viewer in order to iterate through the key/values of the file. For that I decided to go with a qtreewidgetitem where in the first column I would have the key, in the second column the value and in a third column I would like actually to display the values of an numpy array as an image.

For the moment I have written the following script:

```
# Std
import argparse
import collections
import json
import sys
import numpy as np

# External
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel, QFileDialog, QAction
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap

class TextToTreeItem:

    def __init__(self):
        self.text_list = []
        self.titem_list = []

    def append(self, text_list, titem):
        for text in text_list:
            self.text_list.append(text)
            self.titem_list.append(titem)

    # Return model indices that match string
    def find(self, find_str):

        titem_list = []
        for i, s in enumerate(self.text_list):
            if find_str in s:
                titem_list.append(self.titem_list[i])

        return titem_list


class JsonView(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, fpath):
        super(JsonView, self).__init__()

        self.find_box = None
        self.tree_widget = None
        self.text_to_titem = TextToTreeItem()
        self.find_str = ""
        self.found_titem_list = []
        self.found_idx = 0
        self.box_name = ""

        jfile = open(fpath)
        jdata = json.load(jfile, object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)

        box_names = [*self.gen_dict_extract("box_name", jdata)]
        result = len(set(box_names)) == 1
        if result:
            self.box_name = box_names[0]


        # Find UI

        find_layout = self.make_find_ui()

        # Tree

        self.tree_widget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        self.tree_widget.setHeaderLabels(["Key", "Value", "Image"])
        # self.tree_widget.header().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        # self.tree_widget.header().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        root_item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([self.box_name])
        self.recurse_jdata(jdata, root_item)
        self.tree_widget.addTopLevelItem(root_item)
        self.tree_widget.expandToDepth(0)

        # Add table to layout

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.tree_widget)

        # Group box

        gbox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(fpath)
        gbox.setLayout(layout)

        layout2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout2.addLayout(find_layout)
        layout2.addWidget(gbox)

        self.setLayout(layout2)


    def gen_dict_extract(self, key, var):
        if isinstance(var,dict) and hasattr(var, 'items'):
            for k, v in var.items():
                if k == key:
                    yield v
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    for result in self.gen_dict_extract(key, v):
                        yield result
                elif isinstance(v, list):
                    for d in v:
                        for result in self.gen_dict_extract(key, d):
                            yield result
        elif isinstance(var,list):
            for v in var:
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    for result in self.gen_dict_extract(key, v):
                        yield result
                elif isinstance(v, list):
                    for d in v:
                        for result in self.gen_dict_extract(key, d):
                            yield result


    def make_find_ui(self):

        # Text box
        self.find_box = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.find_box.returnPressed.connect(self.find_button_clicked)

        # Find Button
        find_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Find")
        find_button.clicked.connect(self.find_button_clicked)

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.find_box)
        layout.addWidget(find_button)

        return layout

    def find_button_clicked(self):

        find_str = self.find_box.text()

        # Very common for use to click Find on empty string
        if find_str == "":
            return

        # New search string
        if find_str != self.find_str:
            self.find_str = find_str
            self.found_titem_list = self.text_to_titem.find(self.find_str)
            self.found_idx = 0
        else:
            item_num = len(self.found_titem_list)
            self.found_idx = (self.found_idx + 1) % item_num

        self.tree_widget.setCurrentItem(self.found_titem_list[self.found_idx])


    def recurse_jdata(self, jdata, tree_widget):

        if isinstance(jdata, dict):
            for key, val in jdata.items():
                self.tree_add_row(key, val, tree_widget)
        elif isinstance(jdata, list):
            for i, val in enumerate(jdata):
                key = str(i)
                if isinstance(jdata[i],dict) and 'sens_comp' in jdata[i]:
                    key = jdata[i]['sens_comp']
                self.tree_add_row(key, val, tree_widget)
        else:
            print("This should never be reached!")

    def tree_add_row(self, key, val, tree_widget):

        text_list = []

        if isinstance(val,list) and key=='sensorData':
            text_list.append(key)
            val = np.array(val, dtype=object)

            # if len(val.shape) != 1:
            #     val = val.reshape(24,32)

            if len(val.shape) == 1:
                val = val.reshape(-1,8)

            text_list.append(str(val))

            row_item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([key, str(val)])

        elif isinstance(val, dict) or isinstance(val, list):
            text_list.append(key)
            row_item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([key])
            self.recurse_jdata(val, row_item)
        else:
            text_list.append(key)
            text_list.append(str(val))
            row_item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([key, str(val)])

        tree_widget.addChild(row_item)
        self.text_to_titem.append(text_list, row_item)


class JsonViewer(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(JsonViewer, self).__init__()

        self.menu_bar()

        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
            fpath = sys.argv[1]
            json_view = JsonView(fpath)
            self.setCentralWidget(json_view)

        self.resize(640, 480)
        self.setWindowTitle("JSON Viewer")


        self.show()

    def menu_bar (self) :
        # filling up a menu bar
        bar = self.menuBar()
        # File menu
        file_menu = bar.addMenu('File')
        # adding actions to file menu
        open_action = QtWidgets.QAction('Open', self)
        close_action = QtWidgets.QAction('Close', self)
        file_menu.addAction(open_action)
        file_menu.addAction(close_action)

        open_action.triggered.connect(self.openPath)

        # use `connect` method to bind signals to desired behavior
        close_action.triggered.connect(self.close)

    def openPath(self):
        fpath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()

        # fpath = sys.argv[1]
        json_view = JsonView(fpath)

        self.setCentralWidget(json_view)


    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()


def main():
    qt_app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    json_viewer = JsonViewer()
    sys.exit(qt_app.exec_())


if "__main__" == __name__:
    main()
```

and I am trying to visualize the following information (actually all the information is provided as a single line):

```
[{"aquisTime": "11-18-25-723721", "box_version": "001", "sens_board": "54906430-100", "MACaddr_eth0": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", "sensorData": [[0.0, 27.247400283813477, 0.0, 28.69390296936035, 0.0, 28.078027725219727, 0.0, 28.03997230529785, 0.0, 24.897180557250977, 0.0, 24.499963760375977, 0.0, 23.3978214263916, 0.0, 23.5650577545166, 0.0, 23.758142471313477, 0.0, 23.5541934967041, 0.0, 23.370447158813477, 0.0, 24.9819278717041, 0.0, 25.295557022094727, 0.0, 24.3200626373291, 0.0, 24.304040908813477, 0.0, 22.6225528717041], [26.393274307250977, 0.0, 28.582483291625977, 0.0, 27.909997940063477, 0.0, 28.392236709594727, 0.0, 28.00481605529785, 0.0, 25.388696670532227, 0.0, 24.007410049438477, 0.0, 23.434412002563477, 0.0, 23.327539443969727, 0.0, 24.347131729125977, 0.0, 24.070825576782227, 0.0, 24.752283096313477, 0.0, 27.674463272094727, 0.0, 26.057825088500977, 0.0, 24.291162490844727, 0.0, 25.0914249420166, 0.0], [0.0, 26.8185977935791, 0.0, 26.6101016998291, 0.0, 27.82305335998535, 0.0, 28.930749893188477, 0.0, 28.6760196685791, 0.0, 27.718469619750977, 0.0, 24.382287979125977, 0.0, 23.519739151000977, 0.0, 23.821985244750977, 0.0, 23.407678604125977, 0.0, 24.223718643188477, 0.0, 24.299219131469727, 0.0, 26.3620548248291, 0.0, 27.2630558013916, 0.0, 25.204309463500977, 0.0, 24.8760929107666], [24.9536075592041, 0.0, 26.29070472717285, 0.0, 27.222864151000977, 0.0, 29.23284339904785, 0.0, 29.2844181060791, 0.0, 28.030908584594727, 0.0, 26.043237686157227, 0.0, 23.98674964904785, 0.0, 23.5355167388916, 0.0, 23.86419105529785, 0.0, 23.602441787719727, 0.0, 25.0830020904541, 0.0, 25.52703285217285, 0.0, 28.371667861938477, 0.0, 24.92656898498535, 0.0, 26.448205947875977, 0.0], [0.0, 24.1496524810791, 0.0, 25.244165420532227, 0.0, 28.82390785217285, 0.0, 29.858118057250977, 0.0, 28.943506240844727, 0.0, 27.1224308013916, 0.0, 24.10454750061035, 0.0, 23.904870986938477, 0.0, 23.963159561157227, 0.0, 24.309412002563477, 0.0, 24.791040420532227, 0.0, 24.958215713500977, 0.0, 24.861841201782227, 0.0, 25.5935001373291, 0.0, 26.398340225219727, 0.0, 26.2838077545166], [24.494470596313477, 0.0, 24.91155433654785, 0.0, 25.95366859436035, 0.0, 29.70025062561035, 0.0, 29.372522354125977, 0.0, 28.098535537719727, 0.0, 23.87615394592285, 0.0, 23.5194034576416, 0.0, 23.702905654907227, 0.0, 24.23784828186035, 0.0, 24.3256778717041, 0.0, 25.501184463500977, 0.0, 23.957300186157227, 0.0, 25.55767250061035, 0.0, 26.024988174438477, 0.0, 27.061059951782227, 0.0], [0.0, 24.3924503326416, 0.0, 24.31902503967285, 0.0, 23.994043350219727, 0.0, 25.83245277404785, 0.0, 27.86760902404785, 0.0, 25.213464736938477, 0.0, 23.697229385375977, 0.0, 24.060327529907227, 0.0, 23.775232315063477, 0.0, 24.02068519592285, 0.0, 24.35552406311035, 0.0, 24.200159072875977, 0.0, 24.88030433654785, 0.0, 25.765466690063477, 0.0, 28.722192764282227, 0.0, 27.34758949279785], [23.411401748657227, 0.0, 24.815515518188477, 0.0, 23.414087295532227, 0.0, 24.96453285217285, 0.0, 26.157678604125977, 0.0, 26.347681045532227, 0.0, 23.301172256469727, 0.0, 24.099145889282227, 0.0, 23.26299476623535, 0.0, 24.131616592407227, 0.0, 24.30022621154785, 0.0, 24.39019203186035, 0.0, 24.499414443969727, 0.0, 25.25078773498535, 0.0, 26.4195499420166, 0.0, 27.547204971313477, 0.0], [0.0, 24.554773330688477, 0.0, 24.415918350219727, 0.0, 24.222986221313477, 0.0, 24.6810245513916, 0.0, 23.302209854125977, 0.0, 23.7110538482666, 0.0, 23.354944229125977, 0.0, 23.07952308654785, 0.0, 23.18279457092285, 0.0, 23.99627113342285, 0.0, 24.1441593170166, 0.0, 24.74578285217285, 0.0, 24.0407657623291, 0.0, 25.646997451782227, 0.0, 28.602624893188477, 0.0, 28.41668128967285], [24.0495548248291, 0.0, 24.94378089904785, 0.0, 23.739587783813477, 0.0, 24.223840713500977, 0.0, 23.817956924438477, 0.0, 24.2690372467041, 0.0, 23.297449111938477, 0.0, 23.4769229888916, 0.0, 22.755701065063477, 0.0, 23.3546085357666, 0.0, 23.5649356842041, 0.0, 24.7673282623291, 0.0, 24.238183975219727, 0.0, 25.415918350219727, 0.0, 28.852258682250977, 0.0, 31.557764053344727, 0.0], [0.0, 25.1708927154541, 0.0, 25.2442569732666, 0.0, 24.75335121154785, 0.0, 24.432580947875977, 0.0, 24.0013370513916, 0.0, 23.95977210998535, 0.0, 24.051660537719727, 0.0, 23.533716201782227, 0.0, 23.4976749420166, 0.0, 23.9699649810791, 0.0, 23.509180068969727, 0.0, 24.4299259185791, 0.0, 23.87346839904785, 0.0, 26.298608779907227, 0.0, 29.81133460998535, 0.0, 32.801963806152344], [24.9686222076416, 0.0, 25.230737686157227, 0.0, 24.12090492248535, 0.0, 24.8330020904541, 0.0, 24.093530654907227, 0.0, 24.13250160217285, 0.0, 23.650781631469727, 0.0, 23.43535804748535, 0.0, 23.201745986938477, 0.0, 24.51177406311035, 0.0, 24.09893226623535, 0.0, 24.20073890686035, 0.0, 24.4957218170166, 0.0, 25.689172744750977, 0.0, 27.99920082092285, 0.0, 33.069358825683594, 0.0], [0.0, 24.984277725219727, 0.0, 24.74541664123535, 0.0, 24.881860733032227, 0.0, 24.8862247467041, 0.0, 24.106897354125977, 0.0, 23.9283390045166, 0.0, 23.67705726623535, 0.0, 23.661523818969727, 0.0, 23.3705997467041, 0.0, 24.223840713500977, 0.0, 23.91411781311035, 0.0, 24.14556312561035, 0.0, 24.218774795532227, 0.0, 24.572351455688477, 0.0, 26.31304359436035, 0.0, 29.320215225219727], [24.922021865844727, 0.0, 25.5465030670166, 0.0, 25.181848526000977, 0.0, 25.0328311920166, 0.0, 24.540246963500977, 0.0, 24.561731338500977, 0.0, 23.783044815063477, 0.0, 24.41777992248535, 0.0, 23.4245548248291, 0.0, 24.115137100219727, 0.0, 23.5469913482666, 0.0, 24.30474281311035, 0.0, 23.915369033813477, 0.0, 24.704370498657227, 0.0, 24.678918838500977, 0.0, 26.7276554107666, 0.0], [0.0, 25.0797061920166, 0.0, 25.60723304748535, 0.0, 25.208887100219727, 0.0, 24.6856632232666, 0.0, 24.829370498657227, 0.0, 24.5165958404541, 0.0, 24.271814346313477, 0.0, 24.789209365844727, 0.0, 23.733179092407227, 0.0, 23.677026748657227, 0.0, 23.490137100219727, 0.0, 24.016809463500977, 0.0, 24.5273380279541, 0.0, 24.58843421936035, 0.0, 25.003686904907227, 0.0, 24.922754287719727], [25.56633949279785, 0.0, 28.21111488342285, 0.0, 24.992090225219727, 0.0, 24.725061416625977, 0.0, 25.182947158813477, 0.0, 24.303308486938477, 0.0, 24.55571937561035, 0.0, 24.9260196685791, 0.0, 24.511011123657227, 0.0, 23.90618324279785, 0.0, 24.33172035217285, 0.0, 24.201684951782227, 0.0, 25.0439395904541, 0.0, 24.10662269592285, 0.0, 24.121545791625977, 0.0, 25.075098037719727, 0.0], [0.0, 25.8648624420166, 0.0, 25.660181045532227, 0.0, 24.90850257873535, 0.0, 24.78569984436035, 0.0, 24.5445499420166, 0.0, 24.629541397094727, 0.0, 24.470117568969727, 0.0, 25.221155166625977, 0.0, 24.8895206451416, 0.0, 24.377527236938477, 0.0, 23.789026260375977, 0.0, 24.16082191467285, 0.0, 24.84368324279785, 0.0, 24.545007705688477, 0.0, 24.513452529907227, 0.0, 24.727869033813477], [26.7521915435791, 0.0, 25.433618545532227, 0.0, 24.911706924438477, 0.0, 25.127588272094727, 0.0, 24.359338760375977, 0.0, 24.88408851623535, 0.0, 24.20366859436035, 0.0, 24.3344669342041, 0.0, 25.56133460998535, 0.0, 24.5034122467041, 0.0, 24.3403263092041, 0.0, 24.49798011779785, 0.0, 24.347742080688477, 0.0, 25.629236221313477, 0.0, 24.16973304748535, 0.0, 24.77532386779785, 0.0], [0.0, 27.432580947875977, 0.0, 25.407922744750977, 0.0, 25.04790687561035, 0.0, 25.032373428344727, 0.0, 24.75591468811035, 0.0, 24.984766006469727, 0.0, 24.0726261138916, 0.0, 24.694665908813477, 0.0, 24.52007484436035, 0.0, 24.49883460998535, 0.0, 24.015222549438477, 0.0, 24.30108070373535, 0.0, 25.307031631469727, 0.0, 25.149499893188477, 0.0, 24.37603187561035, 0.0, 25.309534072875977], [27.03508949279785, 0.0, 25.10491371154785, 0.0, 24.620569229125977, 0.0, 24.9157657623291, 0.0, 24.773340225219727, 0.0, 24.882715225219727, 0.0, 24.777856826782227, 0.0, 24.66265296936035, 0.0, 24.4468936920166, 0.0, 24.274560928344727, 0.0, 24.427331924438477, 0.0, 23.76751136779785, 0.0, 24.064783096313477, 0.0, 24.4506778717041, 0.0, 24.172388076782227, 0.0, 24.1467227935791, 0.0], [0.0, 24.8056583404541, 0.0, 24.248559951782227, 0.0, 24.90874671936035, 0.0, 25.191797256469727, 0.0, 24.6163272857666, 0.0, 24.895837783813477, 0.0, 24.72405433654785, 0.0, 24.55950355529785, 0.0, 24.4366397857666, 0.0, 24.4924259185791, 0.0, 23.906213760375977, 0.0, 24.440027236938477, 0.0, 24.30083656311035, 0.0, 23.885705947875977, 0.0, 24.707544326782227, 0.0, 23.5994815826416], [24.4078311920166, 0.0, 24.5229434967041, 0.0, 24.397058486938477, 0.0, 24.843835830688477, 0.0, 24.658472061157227, 0.0, 24.904260635375977, 0.0, 24.332971572875977, 0.0, 24.8937931060791, 0.0, 24.77007484436035, 0.0, 24.44011878967285, 0.0, 23.892480850219727, 0.0, 24.33977699279785, 0.0, 24.33587074279785, 0.0, 24.37554359436035, 0.0, 23.89275550842285, 0.0, 24.147912979125977, 0.0], [0.0, 24.730615615844727, 0.0, 24.13128089904785, 0.0, 24.326379776000977, 0.0, 25.565515518188477, 0.0, 24.73760414123535, 0.0, 24.711145401000977, 0.0, 24.516931533813477, 0.0, 24.5921573638916, 0.0, 24.489343643188477, 0.0, 24.31316566467285, 0.0, 24.381433486938477, 0.0, 23.906152725219727, 0.0, 23.602441787719727, 0.0, 24.921167373657227, 0.0, 23.53264808654785, 0.0, 24.28179359436035], [23.799768447875977, 0.0, 24.031763076782227, 0.0, 23.9113712310791, 0.0, 24.697778701782227, 0.0, 25.040552139282227, 0.0, 24.9445743560791, 0.0, 24.569421768188477, 0.0, 24.967676162719727, 0.0, 24.808618545532227, 0.0, 24.8918399810791, 0.0, 24.226831436157227, 0.0, 24.83172035217285, 0.0, 24.483728408813477, 0.0, 23.321191787719727, 0.0, 24.1885929107666, 0.0, 24.445276260375977, 0.0]], "box_model": "DCSMmax", "sens_serNo": [22], "headerVersion": "0021", "sens_i2cAddr": "0x4", "sens_comp": "MLX90640", "aquisDate": "2019-06-14", "hostname": "4d4nx6", "sens_manuf": "Lexis", "box_name": "DCSMmaxNo.22"}]
```

Now I have two difficulties which I am trying to address. The above works fine and correctly loads the keys and values of the different fields. However, for the `sensor_data` key while it is a numpy matrix 24x32, instead of showing it in that form what I get is an output where my matrix is formed with multiple line breaks (`\n`):

[image]
[image]

which I do not really understand why is happening. The other issue that I would like to address is whether it would be possible to visualize these values as a grayscale image on the third column of my treewidget. Something like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by using the pyqtgraph external library and creating the following widget structure:

```
# Tree
self.tree_widget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
self.tree_widget.setHeaderLabels(["Key", "Value", "Image"])
root_item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(["Test Item"])
self.tree_widget.addTopLevelItem(root_item)

# Data
val=numpy.random.normal(size=(32, 24, 3))

# Sub-widgets
tableWidget = pyqtgraph.TableWidget(sortable=False)
tableWidget.setData(val)

im1 = pyqtgraph.ImageView()
im1.setImage(val.T)

self.tree_widget.setItemWidget(root_item, 1, tableWidget)
self.tree_widget.setItemWidget(root_item, 2, im1)
```